# How to position a UIBarButtonItem and add an image to it?

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5, uibarbuttonitem

Screenshot HERE: [Screenshot](http://s14.directupload.net/images/140919/258rbaxv.jpg)

Hey,

I'm not a coder and I don't have a lot of expirience besides some HTML/ CSS. I'm just a regular dude trying to build his first app :)

**This is my current problem:** I want to give each button in the UINavigationBar it's own image and position them so that they are ON the bar instead of hanging off it like shown in the screenshot. I want the left button to be in the most left corner and the right button in the most right plus both of them a bit up.

Right now I've managed to at least give all buttons the same image (via UIBarButtonIteam appearance). Of course that's not my intention. Each button should have it's own image.

Could you please help me out with this? What's the easiest way to get this done? Also I'm using Xcode 5 / iOS 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is surely help for you:

UIImage *bar_img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourbarimage.png"];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:bar_img forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

```
UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *backBtnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage.png"]  ;
[backBtn setBackgroundImage:backBtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(ActionOnClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44);

UIView *backview=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
[backview addSubview:backBtn];

UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backview] ;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
```

Comment: This is it! I had to experiment with the CGRectMake's a bit but I could position the button where it needs to be and it also has a background image. Only problem is the button doesn't work anymore. This is what it was doing before I added your code `_barButton.target = self.revealViewCrontroller` and `_barButton.target = @selector(revealToggle:);`. Can you help me fix this issue?

Comment: I've found the problem myself! While playing around I made the following setting: `GCRectMake(0, 0, 0, 44)];` which probably means that it wasn't a shape anymore but rather a stroke and therefor couldn't be clicked. I changed it to `GCRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];` an now it works like a charm. Props to you! I would love to upvote your answer but I just don't have enough reputition right now :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the appearance proxy (which will style every instance of UIBarButtonItem), you should be using [`initWithImage:style:target:action`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithImage:style:target:action:).

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code May be it will helpful to you....

```
UIButton  *done=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
[done setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIBarButtonItem *done1=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:done];
```

Comment: Thx. But this causes a warning: "Unused variable 'done1'". Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: in above code i want to say u that, add your own button add assign to your navigation bar button.. just like i assign 'done1' button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

It will help you. in both ios 6 and ios 7

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"filer_iphone.png"];
//for only ios 7
if ([UIImage instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(imageWithRenderingMode:)])
{
    image = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
}
UIBarButtonItem *item=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                 initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered      target:self   action:@selector(onSettingsClicked:)];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:rightBarButoom];
```

same apply for the left UIBarButton.

Comment: Thanks alot, but I get a warning: "Undeclared selector 'onSettingsClicked' as well as an error: "Use of undeclared identifier 'rightBarButoom' ". As I mentioned earlier, I'm by no means a coder and I just have no idea what all this means.

Comment: Hey its a selector you have to declare.

Comment: I already tried to google it but I can't seem to understand what that means. From what I got so far I have to call the name of a Method with the paranthesis, right? So do I have to create a Method for the button first?